# Schrodinger cat,another explanation of the phenomena

Tags: epr-experiment, schroedingers-cat

Much was written about Schrodinger's cat.
But I still do not understand one point (may be the crucial one):
is it possible that the cat IS actually in ONE state,dead or alive, but as nobody knows until measured, it appears as being in a superposition? Or is this the very core of the experiment? And yet, what if the box is not opened by a human but by a chimpanzee or another cat, say. Would then the SC state collapse or not?What are the exact conditions under which SC state collapses?

May be a better example would be the EPR paradox. What if the two spacially separated and entangled particles ALREADY are at the same state, though unknown one, BEFORE any measurement?
What is wrong with this interpretation?

Comment: I don't think you should try to think about this analogy as involving an actual cat.  I'm sure that the cat itself will be well aware of whether its still alive regardless of who else "knows".  The point being that projecting quantum superposition onto a macroscopic object doesn't really work that way.

Comment: Your majesty; please DON'T USE CAPITAL LETTERS IN YOUR QUERY as it VEHEMENTLY increases the vagueness; if you really want to emphasize something either _italicise_ it or make it _bold_. Hmmm... I don't know what enjoyment you get by using CAPS;/

Comment: Closely related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/63278/